# Using a .NET-2.0-targeted COM DLL in the GAC on a .NET-4-only system

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, compatibility, regasm, clr4.0

Greetings again,

Following up my previous question, I'm trying to maximize the compatibility of my C#-written Windows Explorer extension.  In particular, I'm interested in making sure it works in an environment in which .NET 4 is installed and .NET 3.5 and below are *not* installed.  One would think there's no problem, but apparently it's not so simple...

There are two problems.  First, non-.NET-4-targeted assemblies flat out **will not** load with CLR 4 unless they have a `.config` file that specifies `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />`.  Even trying to use `ngen` on them will fail without this `.config` file.  But my DLL goes in the GAC.  How do I get a `.config` file in there too?  Others have asked the same thing, and reached the conclusion "well, I'll just make a static Settings class instead."  Obviously I can't do that...

Second problem: When I register my DLL with `regasm.exe`, and then open up the registry to see what it wrote, I see `RuntimeVersion = v2.0.50727` under its CLSID entry.  This also prevents the DLL from loading.  Only after I manually change the `RuntimeVersion` value to `v4.0.30319` does the DLL load.

So what the heck do I have to make my installer do here?  For the first one I have no idea.  For the second, I guess I have to have the installer set the registry's RuntimeVersion manually to whatever .NET version is installed?  That seems too wacky to be true...

Answer (score 0):

.Net 2.0 - 3.5 and .Net 4.0 has two different GAC's, if I recall correctly.

"The size issue is partially solved with .NET 4 installer (x86 + x64) being 54 MB and not embedding full runtime installation packages for previous versions." - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework

So if you install .Net 3.5, you get the previous .Net runtimes.  This might be confusing with .NET 4.0, which does not include these previous runtimes.  I believe this means you need to install .Net 3.5 runtime along-side .Net 4.0 to get <= .Net 3.5 runtimes to install into the GAC.

I also believe if you change the RuntimeVersion, you are getting the .DLL to install into the wrong GAC.  It would be interesting, however, if this does work.  I wouldn't trust it in a real-time environment, but it would be very interesting indeed.

Comment: There's no problem with installing the assembly itself to the GAC.  In fact, it installs to the .NET 3.5 GAC location, even without .NET 3.5 installed.  I doubt the RuntimeVersion in the registry has anything to do with this process, as the GAC installation happens before registration.