# How correctly register 32-bit addin on x86 office running on 64-bit PC?

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in, x86-64, wow64

I can't register COM .dll in my office. 
OS - 64-bit Windows 7; 
 Target Framework of dll is 4.0; 
 Office is 32-bit Word **2007** (x86 Word **2007**)
Addin sets Low Level Keyboard Hook and uses the following unmanaged methods

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProcedure lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);  

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

Below all combinations I tried is shown.
Notes:

- RegAsm 32  means performing
  `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe "my.dll" /codebase`
- RegAsm 64 means performing
  `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe "my.dll" /codebase`
- Normal (CU) means
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\ProgID`
- WOW (CU) means
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\ProgID`
- WOW (LM) means
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\ProgID`
- Registry entry(WOW-CU,Normal-CU and WOW-LM) means creating progID folder with Description,FriendlyName,LoadBehavior in appropriate registry directory which encoded above
- Output is AddinSpy output
- When target cpu bitness!=RegAsm bitness RegAsm command fails, I will not show such obvoius entries in my list.

  1. target=32,regasm=32,registry=WOW(CU),output=no output. Word 2007 doesn't see WOW-CU?
  2. target=x86-64,regasm=64,registry=WOW(CU),output=no output. Word 2007 doesn't see WOW-CU?
  3. target=32,regasm=32,registry=Normal(CU),output=`BadImageFormatException` **But addin works!**
  4. target=x86-64,regasm=64,registry=Normal(CU),output= `Dll Path is not found`.
  5. target=32,regasm=32,registry=WOW(LM),output=`BadImageFormatException` **But addin works!**
  6. target=x86-64,regasm=64,registry=WOW(LM),output=`BadImageFormatException`

I heard that Office 2007 doesn't support registration for all users (local machine) but it looks like it does, as `5` and `6` showed. I mean **Word can see registry WOW node in LM**. On the contrary, WOW6432 nodes in Current User ignored as `1` and `2` showed. So, Word **can't see WOW node in CU.**

How I can register my addin? `3` and `5` make it work but `` `BadImageFormatException `` is so annoying I want to ged rid from it.

Comment: Your conclusions are all accurate.  Surely nobody can guess why a BadImageFormatException would still allow an addin to work, this is not youtube.com.

Comment: @HansPassant, I forgot addition to `BadImageFormatException`  - This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded. However, target framework is 4.0 and my PC has 4.0 Framework installed.

Comment: Word already has the CLR loaded, an old version.  You need a [winword.exe.config file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13237936/17034) that forces CLR v4 to be loaded.

Comment: I can't find .config file, I searched over my PC but failed to find it, I tried to create `winword.exe.config` near WINWORD.EXE but after such action Word can't start.